# I want to split the data into two datasets: a training dataset and a test dataset. ( Time Series Analysis in R)

Tags: r, time-series, forecast

I want to split the data into two datasets: a training dataset and a test dataset. The aim will be to use the training dataset to forecast the value of NOx concentration daily in January 2005. Therefore, the training dataset should incude the first 296 observations (until the last observation of 2004). The test dataset should include the 31 daily observations for January 2005.

The dataset contains 390 instances of daily responses from an array of several metal oxide chemical sensors embedded in an Air Quality Chemical Multisensor Device. The device was located on the field in a significantly polluted area, at road level, within an Italian city. Data were recorded from March 2004 to April 2005 (one year). Ground Truth daily averaged concentrations for Total Nitrogen Oxides (NOx) and Nitrogen Dioxide (NO2) are provided, together with information on weather conditions. Missing values are tagged with the value -200.

Dataset with 391 observations, almost one year from 11/03/2004 to 04/04/2005

[image]

Comment: If df is the name of your dataframe then you can do something like` train =subset(df, Date< as.Date("2004-12-31") )` and `test=subset(df, Date > as.Date("2004-12-31") )` Make sure the date datatype is the right one else you might need to do this `df$Date <- as.Date( as.character(df$Date), "%d-%m-%y")` If you want to get data between specific date you can do this as well `subset(df, Date> "2004-05-31" & Date < "2004-12-31")`

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I suggest,  I included a reproducible example of your dataset (with random values for your variables):

```
set.seed(123)
library(data.table)
N = length(seq(from = 
                 as.Date("2004/03/11"),
               to = as.Date("2005/04/04"),
               by = "days"))
df <- data.table("Date" = seq(from = 
                               as.Date("2004/03/11"),
                             to = as.Date("2005/04/04"),
                             by = "days"),
                "NOx" = rnorm(N),
                "NO2" = rnorm(N),
                "Temp" = rnorm(N),
                'RH' = rnorm(N),
                'AH' = rnorm(N))

head(df)
```

Here is what the dataset looks like :

```
 Date        NOx         NO2       Temp
1: 2004-03-11 -0.1639410  1.48433728 -0.7166330
2: 2004-03-12  0.8985008  1.12176857  0.2304389
3: 2004-03-13  0.6891673 -1.39986065 -0.3868637
4: 2004-03-14 -0.8190232 -1.47609804  0.5087085
5: 2004-03-15  0.3200668  0.05810584 -0.8093966
6: 2004-03-16 -0.4670752 -0.95297664  0.4632159
           RH          AH
1: -0.2789256  0.93052499
2: -1.2931294 -0.58877664
3:  1.1668008  1.10508756
4: -1.4853740  0.99288191
5: -1.4771204 -0.04978804
6: -0.5826404  1.06793716
```

Then, I split the data into train and test according to Date:

```
df_train <- df[Date<="2004/12/31"]
df_test <- df[Date>="2005/01/01" & 
                Date <= "2005/01/31"]
```

So I left out all values after 31st January 2005.
Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Thanks a tonne for responding. The thing is I'm unable to produce my data frame into time series . install.packages("fma")
library(fma)
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(forecast)
install.packages("xts")
AQ = read.csv("/Users/aak/Downloads/AirQualityCourseworkNew.csv")
str(AQ)
AQ$Date_format <- as.Date(AQ$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
AQ
AQ$Date <- NULL
str(AQ)
library(xts)
AQ_ts <- ts(AQ$NOx, frequency = 365, start = c(2004,03))
AQ_ts
decompose(AQ_ts)  I want to use NOx only as I have to forecast.help

Comment: Hello. Do you mean you cannot use data.table ? From the code in your comment, it seems like you could apply the above solution and then transform to time series analysis.